# Looking for the URL syntax to get an authorization code from IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

From the provided samples I got this URL that is supposed to provide an authorization code to the provide callBack URL

https://**CONNECTIONSHOSTNAME**/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=SocialDMS&callback_uri=http%3A%2F%2F_DEVELOPMENTHOSTNAME_%3A_DEVELOPMENTPORT_%2F_DEVELOPMENTServletPath_

The socialdms is registered as an application, but nothing happens.
The callback_uri is accessible from the connections machine.

What logging can I switch on on the Connections Server to troubleshoot this ?

Should the callback_uri be SSL enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback url should be SSL enabled.

To do this you might have to re register your application with Connection server. This might help : 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Registering_an_OAuth_client_with_a_provider_ic40&content=pdcontent

Answer (score 1):

That URL should return an authorization form to the end user.

Does the callback_uri match the value provided when registering the application with Connections?

Please enable logging for com.ibm.ws.security.oauth20.*=all and check the trace.log file.

Comment: es this helped. But where does the service\/oauth20_cb URI come from ? This is a trace.log entry:
    oauth form data is {"state":null,"clientDisplayName":"Social DMS 4 G","scope":null,"authorizationUrl":"https:\/\/connections4.e-office.com\/oauth2\/endpoint\/connectionsProvider\/authorize","response_type":"code","redirect_uri":null,"extendedProperties":{"callback_uri":"http:\/\/eog-fire-ice.appspot.com\/service\/oauth20_cb","username":"MIC"},"client_id":"socialdms4g","nonce":"WtUcdsiVOamp1G62"}

Comment: @mpjjonker The `extendedProperties` dictionary contains optional request parameters besides the mandatory ones (e.g. `client_id`). In your example, this is `callback_uri=http%3A%2F%2F_DEVELOPMENTHOSTNAME_%3A_DEVELOPMENTPORT_%2F_DEVELOPMENTServletPath_`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. the callback_uri should be SSL enabled.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS in the  callback-uri seemed to do the trick